# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, tomcat

When I run the backend on NetBeans 8.2, it shows these errors. I think they are related to data, but the codes and database are seemed to have no problems... Other colleagues can run it without any problems. It happens only to my laptop. I don't know what to do. Please help me out.

Eorror 1 below:

```
30-Nov-2021 20:03:49.193 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
30-Nov-2021 20:03:49.193 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/quickq-api] startup failed due to previous errors
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:101)
    at dao.QueueDao.removeAllCustomersTimerVersion(QueueDao.java:619)
    at util.RunAtDynamicTimeUtil.run(RunAtDynamicTimeUtil.java:94)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Eorror 2 below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:101)
    at dao.QueueDao.removeAllCustomersTimerVersion(QueueDao.java:523)
    at util.RunAtDynamicTimeUtil.run(RunAtDynamicTimeUtil.java:94)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

The relevant code below:
Error 1 is related to `List<Queue> queueList = session.getNamedQuery("Queue.findQueueByBusinessId").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getResultList();`

Error 2 is related to `openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdTuesday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult();` in the `case 2` of the `switch()` statement.

```
public static void removeAllCustomersTimerVersion (Session session) throws IOException
{
    PushNotificationGenerator notification = new PushNotificationGenerator();
    RegisterDao registerDao = new RegisterDao();
    BusinessDao businessDao = new BusinessDao();
    QueueHistoryDao queueHistoryDao = new QueueHistoryDao();
    List<Business> businesses = (List<Business>) session.getNamedQuery("Business.getAll").getResultList();
    List<String> fcmTokens  = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    try {
        TimezoneMapper timezoneMapper = new TimezoneMapper();
        TimeConverHelper timeConverHelper = new TimeConverHelper();


    for (Business business : businesses){
        System.out.println(business.getBusinessId());
        int num = timezoneMapper.getTzInt(business.getLatitude().floatValue(),business.getLongitude().floatValue());
        int cow = timeConverHelper.getDateOfWeek(timezoneMapper.timezoneStrings[num]);

        OpenHours openHours = null;
    switch (cow)
    {
        case 0: {
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdSunday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult();
            break;
        }
        case 1: { 
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdMonday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult(); 
            break; 
        }
        case 2: { 
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdTuesday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult(); 
            break; 
        }
        case 3: { 
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdWednesday").setParameter("businessId",business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult(); 
            break; 
        }
        case 4: { 
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdThursday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult(); 
            break; 
        }
        case 5: { 
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdFriday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult(); 
            break; 
        }
        case 6: { 
            openHours = (OpenHours) session.getNamedQuery("OpenHours.findByIdSaturday").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getSingleResult(); 
            break; 
        }
        default: break;
    }
        int openTime;
        if(openHours.getOpenTime().contains("a"))
        {
            openTime = Integer.parseInt(openHours.getOpenTime().replaceAll("[A-Za-z:]", ""));
            if(openTime < 100)
            {
                openTime = openTime*100;
            }
            if(openTime == 12)
            {
                openTime = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            openTime = Integer.parseInt(openHours.getOpenTime().replaceAll("[A-Za-z:]", "")) + 12;
            if(openTime < 100)
            {
                if(openTime != 24){
                    openTime = openTime*100;
                } else {
                    openTime = (openTime - 12)*100;
                }
            }
            else if (openTime >= 1200 && openTime <1300){
                openTime = openTime - 12;
            }
            else
            {
                openTime = openTime - 12 + 1200;
            }
        }
        int closeTime;
        if(openHours.getCloseTime().contains("a"))
        {
            closeTime = Integer.parseInt(openHours.getCloseTime().replaceAll("[A-Za-z:]", ""));
            if(closeTime < 100)
            {
                closeTime = closeTime*100;
            }                   
            if(closeTime == 12)
            {
                closeTime = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            closeTime = Integer.parseInt(openHours.getCloseTime().replaceAll("[A-Za-z:]", "")) + 12;
            System.out.println("closeTime testing: " + closeTime);
            if(closeTime < 100)
            {
                if(closeTime != 24){
                    closeTime = closeTime*100;
                } else {
                    closeTime = (closeTime - 12)*100;
                }
                System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.println(closeTime);
            } 
            else if (closeTime >= 1200 && closeTime <1300){
                closeTime = closeTime - 12;
            }
            else
            {
                closeTime = closeTime - 12 + 1200;
            }
        }
        
        Date now = timeConverHelper.localTimeToGivenTimezone(timezoneMapper.timezoneStrings[num]);
        SimpleDateFormat Formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
        String dateNow = "";
        dateNow = Formatter.format(now);
        
        if (Integer.parseInt(dateNow) < openTime || Integer.parseInt(dateNow) > closeTime||!business.getIsVisable()) {
            System.out.println("the business has been closed from function removeAllCustomersTimerVersion");
            List<Queue> queueList = session.getNamedQuery("Queue.findQueueByBusinessId").setParameter("businessId", business.getBusinessId()).getResultList();
            Collections.reverse(queueList);

            if(!queueList.isEmpty()){
                for(Queue queue:queueList) {
                    System.out.println("start to get ticket using queue id: " + queue.getQueueId());
                    Ticket ticket = null;

                    try {
                       ticket = (Ticket) session.getNamedQuery("Ticket.findTicketByQueueId").setParameter("queueId", queue.getQueueId()).getSingleResult();
                       System.out.println("get ticket using queue id successfully");
                    }  catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("no ticket find, but it is alright, ignore it");
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    queue.setQueueNumber(-1);

                    queue.setModifiedDate(timeConverHelper.localTimeToUTC());
                    queue.setDeletedDate(timeConverHelper.localTimeToUTC());
                    System.out.println("update queue successfully");
                    if (ticket != null) {
                        System.out.println("start update ticket");
                    ticket.setQueueNumber(-1);
                    ticket.setIsCancelled(true);
                    ticket.setModifiedDate(timeConverHelper.localTimeToUTC());
                    ticket.setDeletedDate(timeConverHelper.localTimeToUTC());

                     List<Register> registers = registerDao.getFCMToken(ticket.getUserId(), session);
                     for(Register r:registers )
                     {
                          fcmTokens.add(r.getFcmToken());
                     }

                    session.saveOrUpdate(ticket);
                    queueHistoryDao.convertTicketToQueueHistoryTimerVersion(ticket, session);
                    }
                    session.saveOrUpdate(queue);
                }
            }
                        // if no token in the list, dont call the pushnotification function
            if(!fcmTokens.isEmpty()){
                //notification.pushNotification(fcmTokens, business.getBusinessName() + " is closed. Your ticket has been cancelled", " ");
                notification.pushNotification(fcmTokens,"Your ticket has been cancelled", " ");
                fcmTokens.clear();
            }

            System.out.println("fcmTokens is empty, don't have notification to send");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("the business is still open");
        }
        }
        


       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cannot remove queue for unknown reason: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // session.getTransaction().commit();
    // session.close();
}
```